# InApp Purchases - paymentQueue: updatedTransactions is not called from specific place

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have two places when I initiate the same UIView with possibility to buy an InApp purchasable product.
1. End of user onboarding
2. Standard place in menu

From the 1st one the payment is initiated I get to the updatedTransactions with SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray     *)transactions
{
  DLog(@"updatedTransactions");
  for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
  {
    switch (transaction.transactionState)
    {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            // I get here when the controller is initiated from menu, not from my user onboarding
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            [self failedTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
            // I get here
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
  }
}
```

But then this method is never called when user finish the transaction.

When I initiate the same controller from the menu everything works fine.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Which class is implementing this transactionObserver and at what place are you setting the transactionObserver?

Comment: I'm using another class for managing payments - CCPaymentsHelper.shared().buyProductIdentifier(product.productIdentifier) 

the class CCPayments is child of IAHelper which is implementing this transactionObserver

Comment: and you are adding the transaciton observer in init method of this CCPAymentsHelper class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you are setting the wrong transaction observer (or not setting it) in one of the two mentioned controllers.

In order to receive notifications when a transaction is updated, you have to add the observer this way:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:something];
```

where `something` can be `self` (if your `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` method is on `self`) or another object.

If you post the relevant code of the two controllers (controller names and calls to the `addTransactionObserver:` method mentioned above plus a bit of context) I can give you more informations, but until then I can make some assumption.

Let's assume that you have two controllers:

`UserOnboardingController`
`UpgradeController`

You say that in the `UpgradeController` it works correctly, this is probably because when the controller is loaded (in `viewDidLoad:` for example) there is a call to

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
```

and the `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` is one of the methods of `UpgradeController`.

However, when you are on `UserOnboardingController`, you don't call or pass the wrong observer to `addTransactionObserver:` method.

If this is the situation, you should:

- retrieve the correct observer from your ViewController hierarchy and pass in as observer
- move the code of the transaction observer on a shared class (for example on the `AppDelegate` or another specific singleton class)